Images disappearing even though BLOB data still rendering correctly
After using my Expo React Native app and switching screens, all the images disappear. I then look at the logs and the blob data is displayed correctly. I think it might be a caching issue, but I have no idea why it would work at the start and then suddenly stop working. Please help.
Here is a code snippet:
const MenuItem = ({ item }) => {
  const images = useImages();
  const { name, id: catalogItemId, price } = item;

  const imageUrl = images.get(catalogItemId);
  const imageClassName = "w-full h-[120px] rounded-t-[10px]";

  console.log(imageUrl+ `?timestamp=${Date.now()}`);

  return (
    <Pressable 
      onPress={() => router.push(`item/${catalogItemId}/-1`)} 
      className="flex-1 bg-white shadow-custom m-3 rounded-[10px]"
    >
      <Image
        className={imageClassName}
        source={{ uri: imageUrl + `?timestamp=${Date.now()}` }}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />

      <View className="w-full h-[90px] flex items-center px-3">
        <Text className="font-koulen text-primary text-center text-[20px] leading-5 pt-4">{name}</Text>
        <Text className="font-kokoro text-primary text-[14px]">${price.toFixed(2)}</Text>
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  );
}

I thought the issue had to do with caching, but everything I have tried doesn't seem to fix the issue.
